# Firebase orderByChild not working for newly entered data (new data since ~24 hours ago)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a users object in Firebase's database, and I am using orderByChild('email') to find users by email. The field is indexed.

Something strange since recently (since ~24 hours ago) -- it doesn't work on newly entered users.

I can fetch data that was there days ago, but not data that was entered within the last day.

I can do something like usersRef.child(userUID) and find a user fine -- it's really just the orderByChild that's failing.

Do you experience this with your own Firebase and have you found a fix?

Comment: That sounds strange. Can you add a minimal, complete snippet of code that reproduces the problem. Even better would be to also have a link to a jsbin that allows us to see the problem in action.

Comment: It can be in a rest call like such: `https://myApp.firebaseio.com/users.json?orderBy="lowerCaseUsername"&equalTo="{username}"`

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/eLddUreeukU

Comment: Right I created on Firebase's Google group as well to try and reach a wider audience.

Comment: Does this happen to you too on new data? (orderByChild on some indexed property doesn't return the existing data) or is it only me?

Comment: I haven't had problems getting data, nor seen other reports. Hence the request for a jsbin that allows me to see the same thing you are having. It's really the fastest way to get us on the same page.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Added to the post

Comment: Nevermind, it works on another Firebase so I'll debug some more on why my new users on my main Firebase can't be retrieved.

Comment: If the problem only happens when using the REST API: that is expected. Since the REST API returns a regular JSON object, it cannot return the keys in a specific order. So when accessing Firebase through the REST API, you can only use `orderBy` to filter data and should always do the final sorting client-side. That is essentially also what the SDKs do.

Comment: It doesn't work with the JS API either. `usersRef.orderByChild('username').equalTo(username).......`

Comment: Also it's always just one item - the REST API works fine for old data but not new data. It's really weird. Still investigating what could be different in the data set.

Comment: OK. If you can repro, set up a jsbin that reproduces it and I'll have a look. As it stands there simply isn't enough code/JSON to go on.